# Using stacks to check balance of HTML tags

Tags: c++, stack

I'm trying to write a program that will tell me if all the tags in an HTML file are balanced, so every `<tag>`  has a `</tag>`. I'm not worried about the self closing tags at this point. What I have I thought would work, but isn't quite right. It's looking at each element instead of looking for the open and closing tags as a whole. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
const string opening = "<*>";
const string closing = "</*>";
string input;



int main()
{
    char element;
    stack<char> stk;
    ifstream file;

    cout << "Please Enter File name: ";
         cin >> input;

    //std::file.open(input);

    file.open(input.c_str());

    if(file.fail())
        cout<<"File is corrupt or does not exists!"<<endl;

    while(!file.eof())
    {
        file>>element;

        //push left group symbols onto stack
        if(element==opening[0])
            stk.push(element);
        else if(element==opening[1])
            stk.push(element);
        else if(element==opening[2])
            stk.push(element);

    }
    file.close();
    file.open(input.c_str());
    while(!file.eof())
    {
        file>>element;

        if(stk.top()==opening[0])
        {
            if(element==closing[0])
                stk.pop();
        }
        else if(stk.top()==opening[1])
        {
            if(element==closing[1])
                stk.pop();
        }
        else if(stk.top()==opening[2])
        {
            if(element==closing[2])
                stk.pop();
        }
    }
    file.close();

    if(!stk.empty())
        cout<<"\nILLEGAL"<<endl;
    else if(stk.empty())
        cout<<"\nLEGAL"<<endl;

    cout << "\n\nProgram complete." <<  endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm fairly new to C++ and especially stacks so please explain answers so that I might learn.

Comment: Are the tags in the file literally composed of `<*>` and `</*>`? Also, remember it's legal to have something like `<br/>`.

Comment: `while (!file.eof()) file >> element;` is better replaced with `while (file >> element)`. See [this question](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/istream-and-eof.html) for an explanation of that.

Comment: I've been testing this a bit.  I used a file containing this:
<*></*><*></*>
And I've found that for some reason, when rereading the file, it reads the last character twice.

Comment: @chris No the file is not composed of `<*>` and `</*>`. I thought having the * would assume anything could be there. Would I instead need to have something like `"<" && ">"` and `"</" && ">"`? Also, I realize `<br/>` is legal, but for this case I don't need to worry about that. And thanks for the `.eof` tip!

Comment: @Fourthmeal70, There's no concept of wildcards in C++ I know of, but you *can* use `std::string` to ease the pain. You can pull out the parts between each `<` and `>` with `find()` and `substr()`, to name a couple. Perhaps a Boost parsing library, or, if you just want the finished product, an actual HTML parsing library, would better fit your needs.

Comment: @chris, I don't want the finished product. I'm trying to learn C++ with a book that I have and it had me write a stack to check balance of () {} [] in a text file and I did that ok. So I decided to try to check html tags, but its a little more challenging that I had initially thought. I will try changing my code to use `find()` or `substr()`.

Answer (score 0):

I found your error.  You say this:

```
 if(stk.top()==opening[0])
    {
        if(element==closing[0])
            stk.pop();
    }
    else if(stk.top()==opening[1])
    {
        if(element==closing[1])
            stk.pop();
    }
    else if(stk.top()==opening[2])
    {
        if(element==closing[2])
            stk.pop();
    }
```

opening[0] = '<' and closing[0] = '<' so that's okay.  But unfortunately, that doesn't hold true for the rest of the characters:

opening[1] = '*' and closing[1] = '/'

Unfortunately, even when I change the code to this:

```
 if(stk.top()==opening[0])
    {
        if(element==closing[0])
            stk.pop();
    }
    else if(stk.top()==opening[1])
    {
        if(element==closing[2])
            stk.pop();
    }
    else if(stk.top()==opening[2])
    {
        if(element==closing[3])
            stk.pop();
    }
```

it still does not work.  I'll look into it further.

Comment: I realize it is looking at the individual characters, but I think I need it to find the opening `<` and ignore everying till it finds `>` then push.  and pop once it finds the corresponding `</`again ignoring untill it finds `>`.

Comment: My point was that you were mismatching the characters.  If you ignore everything in between, then you don't know if you're encountering the correct corresponding `</`.  Say you have a file that reads <file></endoffile>.  You'll see a `<`, a `>`, a `</`, and another `>`, but what's in between does not match up.